# Refactoring record retrieval in Rails controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

[image]

I have the code above and the following route's `resources` :

```
resources :products, only:[:index] do
  resources :orders, :path => 'order', only:[:new, :create],
    path_names: {new: ""}
end
```

May I know if the code in #4 and #9 could be refactored since they're doing the same thing and I've read that programming in Ruby always encourage DRY code. Learning to be a better programmer here. Thanks for the tips and advice.

Comment: Please add code snippets instead of image

Answer (score 1):

As Deepak mentioned, `before_action` is one idea. Personally, I prefer a lazy accessor. Its advantages are:

- The models are references directly in the action, not somewhere else in the file. It's easier to see which models are used by an action.
- The dependencies are figured out automatically. If you use `order` then `product` is loaded automatically without having to loading it manually.

The code should look like:

```
def new
  product
end

def create
  if order.save
    redirect_to(products_path)
  else
    render(:new)
  end
end

private

def product
  @product ||= Product.find(params[:product_id])
end

def order
  @order ||= product.orders.build(order_params)
end
```

Note that I  made two minor changes (that you may get rid of):

1. I build an order (instead of creating it) and test whether `order.save` returns a truthy value.
2. I don't pass errors in a flash. I assume they're rendered in the form rendered by `new.html.erb`.

Feel free to discard these changes if they don't fit your application.

Comment: Nice approach, although calling just `product` in `new` isn't very descriptive. I would consider adding `alias :set_product :product` below the definition of `product`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add it to `before_action` and remove from `new` and `create` actions

Now `@product` will be assigned before `new` and `create` action

```
before_action :find_product, only: [:new, :create]

private

def find_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
end
```